# Agrupar filas de 3 en 3 con Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un `DataFrame` cuyo índice es de tipo `DateTime`, los tiempos del índice no son continuos. Podéis ver que los tres primeros datos están en secuencia y después del tercer dato pasa directamente al minuto 50. Todo el `DataFrame` goza de esta característica.

```
datos_frecuencia
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

                        Estado
2021-05-07 19:45:00      1.0
2021-05-07 19:46:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 19:47:00      0.0
2021-05-07 19:50:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 19:51:00      1.0
2021-05-07 19:52:00      1.0
2021-05-07 19:55:00      1.0
2021-05-07 19:56:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 19:57:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:00:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:01:00      1.0
2021-05-07 20:02:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:05:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:06:00      1.0
2021-05-07 20:07:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:10:00      0.0
2021-05-07 20:11:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:12:00      1.0
2021-05-07 20:15:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:16:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:17:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:20:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:21:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:22:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:25:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:26:00      0.0
2021-05-07 20:27:00     -1.0
```

Necesito agrupar este `DataFrame` en grupos de 3 en 3, para realizar la suma de la columna *Estado*.

He intentado usar `resample()`, de la siguiente manera.

```
datos_frecuencia["Estado"].resample("3min").sum()

2021-05-07 19:54:00    0
2021-05-07 19:57:00   -1
2021-05-07 20:00:00   -1
2021-05-07 20:03:00   -1
2021-05-07 20:06:00    0
2021-05-07 20:09:00   -1
2021-05-07 20:12:00    1
2021-05-07 20:15:00   -3
2021-05-07 20:18:00   -1
2021-05-07 20:21:00   -2
2021-05-07 20:24:00   -1
2021-05-07 20:27:00   -1
```

Pero el resultado no es el esperado, ya que de esta manera, `resample()` toma tiempos que en el `DataFrame` original no existe. Por ejemplo `resample` muestra:  `2021-05-07 20:03:00   -1`,  cuando el minuto 3 de la hora 20, no se encuentra en el `DataFrame` principal.

Necesitaría que se agrupara de la siguiente manera, tomando la suma de la columna *estado*:

```
                        Estado
[2021-05-07 19:45:00     1.0
2021-05-07 19:46:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 19:47:00      0.0]

[2021-05-07 19:50:00    -1.0
2021-05-07 19:51:00      1.0
2021-05-07 19:52:00      1.0]

[2021-05-07 19:55:00     1.0
2021-05-07 19:56:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 19:57:00     -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:00:00    -1.0
2021-05-07 20:01:00      1.0
2021-05-07 20:02:00     -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:05:00    -1.0
2021-05-07 20:06:00      1.0
2021-05-07 20:07:00     -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:10:00     0.0
2021-05-07 20:11:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:12:00      1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:15:00    -1.0
2021-05-07 20:16:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:17:00     -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:20:00    -1.0
2021-05-07 20:21:00     -1.0
2021-05-07 20:22:00     -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:25:00    -1.0
2021-05-07 20:26:00      0.0
2021-05-07 20:27:00     -1.0]
```

El resultado final deberia ser un dataFrame con los siguientes datos:

```
                        Estado
[2021-05-07 19:45:00     0.0]

[2021-05-07 19:50:00     1.0]

[2021-05-07 19:55:00    -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:00:00    -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:05:00    -1.0]

[2021-05-07 20:10:00     0.0]

[2021-05-07 20:15:00    -3.0]

[2021-05-07 20:20:00    -3.0]

[2021-05-07 20:25:00    -2.0]
```

¿Vosotr@s conocéis alguna función en Pandas, con la que pueda obtener este resultado?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo recorriendo el DF y escogiendo 3 valores `DF[: 3]` solo deberas remplazar esto por cada iteracion agregando 3

Comment: Gracias Christian por tu comentario, la verdad lo tengo así, quisiera eliminar tantos ciclos (for) de mi código, me parece que pandas es más rápido en cuanto a iteraciones y visualmente es más agradable, el código queda más prolijo usando pandas.

Answer (score 0):

No pude encontrar una solución, en una sola linea, así que se me ocurrió *(inicialmente)*...

Agrupar los datos por separado *(fechas y sumas)*, y crear un nuevo DataFrame con estos datos.

A modo de ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Crear el DataFrame
datos_frecuencia = pd.DataFrame([1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1], index=['2021-05-07 19:45:00', '2021-05-07 19:46:00', '2021-05-07 19:47:00', '2021-05-07 21:50:00', '2021-05-07 21:51:00', '2021-05-07 21:52:00', '2021-05-07 22:55:00', '2021-05-07 22:56:00', '2021-05-07 22:57:00'], columns=['Estado'])

# Agrupar y sumar los datos
suma = datos_frecuencia.groupby(np.array(range(9))//3).sum()

# Extraer las fechas
index = datos_frecuencia[[True, False, False]*3].index

# Crear un nuevo DataFrame
agrupacion = pd.DataFrame(suma['Estado'].tolist(), index=index, columns=['Suma'])

# Resultado
print(agrupacion)
                     Suma
2021-05-07 19:45:00     0
2021-05-07 21:50:00     1
2021-05-07 22:55:00    -1
```

***Otra posible solución*** *(Mucho más elegante!)*

Es usar agg(), realiza todo el procedimiento en una sola linea. Lo que no me gusta es tener que convertir el index (DateTime) a un index (Integer)

Gracias a Julio Jesus
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/94320/grouping-with-non-sequential-index-datetime-pandas-python/94321#94321

Al inicio estaba muy bien explicada, pero ha sido tan editada... que ahora quedo inservible.

El código seria algo así:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Crear el DataFrame
datos_frecuencia = pd.DataFrame([1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1], index=['2021-05-07 19:45:00', '2021-05-07 19:46:00', '2021-05-07 19:47:00', '2021-05-07 21:50:00', '2021-05-07 21:51:00', '2021-05-07 21:52:00', '2021-05-07 22:55:00', '2021-05-07 22:56:00', '2021-05-07 22:57:00'], columns=['Estado'])

# Reiniciar el index, convierte el index (DateTime) en un index (Integer)
datos_frecuencia = datos_frecuencia.reset_index()

# Re-nombramos las columnas (OPCIONAL)
datos_frecuencia.columns = ['Fecha','Estado']

# La magia de Pandas!, agrupamos por una frecuencia de tres (datos_frecuencia.index//3).
# Agregamos agg() para usar más de operaciones sobre el grupo especificado.
# "Fecha":lambda x: x.head(3).min()    # Hacemos cabeceras de 3 filas y tomamos la menor
# "Estado":sum                         # Hacemos una suma de la columna 'Estado'

datos_frecuencia.groupby(datos_frecuencia.index // 3).agg({"Fecha":lambda x: x.head(3).min(),"Estado":sum})
```

**Resultado:**

```
                 Fecha  Estado
0  2021-05-07 19:45:00       0
1  2021-05-07 21:50:00       1
2  2021-05-07 22:55:00      -1
```